# Problem to install .NET 4.6 using Wine

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm quite new using Wine so I'm gonna list i've done:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine-devel
export WINEARCH=win32
winecfg
sudo apt-get winetricks
```

After that, i went to https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32828

Downloaded the 4.6 Offline Installer available there

Then, on terminal

```
 cd ~/Downloads/ (where the installer was)

 wine NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q (silent installation)
```

A large result comes after that (couldn't post because filter does not allow it)

Then I check dotnet installed :

```
winetricks list-installed

Result: dotnet40
        dotnet45
```

*Both 4.0 and 4.5 were installed  using winetricks GUI before installing 4.6.

I really dont know what is the problem with 4.6 installation. Someone successfully installed this ? Really appreciate any help !

Ubunt 16.04 LTS
Wine version got : 2.1 (development)

Thanks

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32828&iTestingId=95320

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good news: I was able to solve the problem by installing Wine 2.0 using Ricotz's PPA and using its more updated winetricks.

First, remove last installation (in my case it was wine-devel)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine-devel*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Get Ricotz wine 2.0:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/unstable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine2.0
```

Create other prefix (e.g. : .wine32), set WINEARCH to win32 and run winecfg:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
"Set Windows 7"
```

Then run winetricks using the last configurations:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 winetricks
```

Now go *Select Default Winetricks -> Install a Windows DLL or components -> dotnet46* and install it.

Wine will download and install dotnet46 and other requirements. Even if asking for Mono, it continues to download more and more requirements until it's able to install .NET 4.6 (there was no need to have Mono for me).

Comment: I am unable to install .NET 6.4.1 using this method, which is required by memoQ. Have you managed to do that yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a issue regarding .NET 4.6. After trying so many ways this worked for me.

- I downloaded dotnet46 from here: https://winegui.melroy.org/downloads/WineGUI-v1.9.2.deb
- Then installed it through WineGUI
- In WineGUI, [Uninstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRMxx.png) -> [Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QCE3.png) -> [Change 'Files of Type' as 'Programs(*.exe)'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYqAJ.png) -> Locate previously downloaded dotnet exe file
- Done