# Coming [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine

While i am trying to run `PKHeX.exe` using `wine`, it is coming like the below:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'PKHeX.WinForms.Main+<>c:<>9__61_0' (7) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'PKHeX.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) PKHeX.WinForms.Main..ctor()
  at PKHeX.WinForms.Program.Main () [0x0001c] in <f1590b2482bb4ff1be7d523a13a71c2d>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'PKHeX.WinForms.Main+<>c:<>9__61_0' (7) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'PKHeX.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) PKHeX.WinForms.Main..ctor()
  at PKHeX.WinForms.Program.Main () [0x0001c] in <f1590b2482bb4ff1be7d523a13a71c2d>:0 Cannot load assembly mscorlib
0009:err:mscoree:RuntimeHost_ExitProcess Process should have exited
0009:err:mscoree:expect_no_runtimes Process exited with a Mono runtime loaded.
```

Check also the following picture for reference:
[image: Unhandled Exception]

Can somebody check this problem?

Comment: PKHeX is an open-source save file editor for the main series of Pokémon games, allowing you to transfer Pokémon data between saves, customize them to your liking, and much more. As PKHeX is available for Windows and Mac only, this question is about how to install it in Ubuntu with Wine.

Answer (score 0):

Either the version of Wine you're using has bugs/built wrong/missing libraries or you didn't install the required version of .Net (NET Framework 4.6 or later) using winetricks. <sup>[source](https://projectpokemon.org/home/forums/topic/57536-has-anyone-managed-to-make-a-linux-build-for-pkhex/)</sup>. See [Problem to install .NET 4.6 using Wine](https://askubuntu.com/q/881435/). ppa:ricotz/unstable includes wine 5.0 in Ubuntu 20.04.

Installing PKHeX in Ubuntu is like the tail wagging the dog. Because of possible package management issues that could be caused by using ppa:ricotz/unstable in Ubuntu 20.04 it makes sense to install the small PKHeX application in Windows instead of in Ubuntu if you have a device with Windows installed on it. Unless you're going to install a lot of garbage Windows programs in Ubuntu anyway.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install winetricks
```